# Select a path inside an object with script

Tags: python, objects

I'm writing a script where I need to rename the path493 in order to select and apply bevel_depth. I don't understand how to do it. Been reading the API documentation, but as I'm not a developer it's not clear why there's a difference between the Curve_1 object and the path493 when applying the bevel depth.

Could you point me in the right direction as to what should I read to understand how this works?

[image]

Comment: `C.active_object.data.name = C.active_object.name` `Curve_1` is Object and `path493` is Data inside an object.

Comment: Worked! I've been trying things for hours on this. Thank you!